# Java RegEx to negate part of the string in a pattern

Tags: java, regex

Below is a basic java method from which i am trying to find a pattern.

```
 public static void stringFilter() {
    int compVal = 33331;
    List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("app_Usage_RTIS/batch_id=11111/abc");
        add("ENV_RTIS/batch_id=22222/");
        add("ABCD-EFG_RTIS/batch_id=33333/");
        add("/RTIS/batch_id=44444/");
        add("/batch_id=55555/");
    }};

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*_RTIS/batch_id=(\\d+)/.*");

    for (String s : strList) {
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            System.out.println(s + "\tTrue");
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is working fine for me to select string which contains `"_RTIS/batch_id=123***/"` but my idea is to select only String which doesn't include `"_RTIS"` but it to include "/batch_id=123***/".
I tried doing

```
`Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*(!_RTIS)/batch_id=(\\d+)/.*");`
```

But it didn't worked for me.

To make it clear, my output should select only ->

```
"/RTIS/batch_id=44444/" True
"/batch_id=55555/" True
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ware close. You could use [negative-look-behind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) `(?<!...)` to require that before `/batch_id=(\\d+)` part there is no match for `_RTIS`.

So your regex can look like: `".*(?<!_RTIS)/batch_id=(\\d+)/.*"`.

Demo:

```
List<String> strList = Arrays.asList(
    "app_Usage_RTIS/batch_id=11111/abc",
    "ENV_RTIS/batch_id=22222/",
    "ABCD-EFG_RTIS/batch_id=33333/",
    "/RTIS/batch_id=44444/",
    "/batch_id=55555/"
);

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*(?<!_RTIS)/batch_id=(\\d+)/.*");
for (String s : strList) {
    if (pattern.matcher(s).matches()) {
        System.out.println(s + "\tTrue");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
/RTIS/batch_id=44444/   True
/batch_id=55555/    True
```

Comment: Thanks..it worked for me. And can you please narrate the use of "?<!"

Comment: @PrabhuLingappaAS You are welcome, but I am not sure if I would be able to explain it better than linked article. If after reading that tutorial something is still not clear ask about that specific part.